# Whoops! We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later

Tags: codeigniter-4

> **Whoops!** We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later.

Codeigniter 4 shows an error when I run the CI4 application, How I resolve?

Changes:

```
public $baseURL = 'http://ci.local';


public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
public $indexPage = '';
```

Comment: Did you change anything else except `$basURL` ?

Comment: i know this is outdated article but may this help you https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/581

Comment: this helped me thanks thanks

Answer (score 46):

This work for me try it
Go to app directory then to boot directory you will see production.php file.

That is:
`app => Config => Boot => production.php`

Change the `ini_set('display_errors', '0')` to `ini_set('display_errors', '1')`.

Warning: When in production change back to initial `ini_set('display_errors', '0')`

Or

you can rename your file `env` in your project directory to `.env`  after that open it and edit.
Search for `# CI_ENVIRONMENT = production`  remove `#` and change `production` to `development`

Warning: When in production change back to initial `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development` to `CI_ENVIRONMENT = production`

For those experiencing intl error go to where your php installation directory  edit the php.ini file remove `semi-colon` `";"` from `;extension=intl` to `extension=intl`. save the file and restart your server. I think this will solve that error. This particular editing of my php.ini was on php >= 7.3 so I haven't check other version of php lesser than these versions which Codeigniter 4 does not support

Comment: Setting ```CI_ENVIRONMENT = development``` in ```env``` strangely did not change anything. 
But changing ```production.php``` as you described did the job. 
However, I am wondering, why did changing the ```env``` file not help?

Comment: @Gerke Did you change file `env` to `.env` that is adding dot in front of the file name. I hope this will do the job for you

Comment: @user9437856 what are you using

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Changing environment to "development" did the magic because Codeigniter 4* already set that `display_errors` to `'1'` by default.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin Off course, that is the reason I give the possible solution I know you can use to solve this error

Comment: Since this is Codeigniter 4, rather I'd suggest only the CI_ENVIRONMENT modification in the .env from "production" to "development". In  my case no exception thrown but just an info to enable CURL in the php.ini. Anyway good reminder, forgot to set it.

Answer (score 18):

After installing CodeIgniter 4 when you run the app then you will get an error like this

[image]

To know the error go to the **app/Config/Boot/production.php** and set display_errors to 1 as below

ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Now, you will see the actual error below

[image]

Nothing to worry about it. The app needs permission. Assign the permission like as below

sudo chmod -R 777 project_name

Answer (score 14):

Assume that your root folder of your CI4 project is `rootproject`.
Edit `rootproject/.env` file.
On line 17 change from:

```
#  CI_ENVIRONMENT = production
```

to:

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```

Save it.

Refresh your browser that pointing to your CI4 project.
It should give you many error messages.

If there is something written as `CacheException`, than your cache folders are not writable.
Make it writable;

Ubuntu:

```
chown -Rv www-data rootproject/writable
```

CentOS:

```
chown -Rv apache rootproject/writable
```

Easy way:

```
chmod 777 -Rv rootproject/writable
```

Comment: Never use 777, pleease

Answer (score 7):

In your CI4 project root, create a file named `.env`. It should be in the same directory as system, app e.t.c

Then, add this `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is most likely due to missing extensions. Check [server requirements here.](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/intro/requirements.html). Check your php.ini file and make sure **intl** and **mbstring** are enabled.

Comment: Here's a solution for enable **intl** answered by @burhan-ul-haqq-zahir [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100302/6681157](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100302/6681157)

Comment: Yes, also stated on this website: 
https://www.studentstutorial.com/codeigniter/install_4.php?expand_article=1

Answer (score 6):

When you change # CI_ENVIRONMENT = production to CI_ENVIRONMENT = development don't forget of rename the env file to .env else it will not work.

Answer (score 5):

Try This

1. Open [xampp]/php/php.ini

   Search for **;extension=intl** and remove the **;**
2. Save the php.ini file and restart Apache(server).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I have a simple solution for Mac.
- in the project folder, go to 'writable'
- select all the folders contained and click on 'get information'
- go share and permissions
- in 'everyone' select 'read and write'
That's it! refresh the page

Comment: I'm using Mac too. A simple way and it works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

1. In Root folder change: *env* to *.env*
2. Change `# CI_ENVIRONMENT = production` to `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development` (ensure it is uncommented)
3. Your error may be related to the *knit.php* file.
   Go to *System/Third Party* and change: *knit.php* to *Knit.php* (Capital)
4. Reload.

Comment: I have downloaded ci4 manually, After follow these steps, got same issue

Answer (score 3):

For those using XAMPP in MacOS:

You don't need to change the ownership of the writable directory. You only need to change permission to entire directory:

```
chmod -R 777 writable
```

Comment: Your answer fits better in the StackOverflow format when you answer the whole question. You could cite other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You're running in the production environment and need to change it to a Development or Testing environment to see the error messages within the browser.

There are a few ways to do this, but adding:

```
SetEnv CI_ENVIRONMENT development
```

To the Apache httpd.config file is what worked for me.

_t

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer for this query; just follow these steps:

1. From the command line, at your project root just hit this
   `php spark serve`
2. Then hit this on your browser `http://localhost:8080/`

Enjoy your Latest CI.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the desired answer is, but:

1. If you are asking to see what is the actual error is - either change
   your environment to testing/development (as suggested so far) or you
   can check your logs - writable/logs/log-.php
2. If you wish to solve the error, we will need more information, like have
   you setup virtual hosts, have you change .htaccess file in public
   folder, etc. Otherwise we will be most likely betting (I bet it's virtual hosts).

In any case, a copy of the displayed error (after changing evnironment) or log file will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter 4 source code have a folder named **writable**, just update it's access permission. Sometimes it'll help to get rid of Whoops. [Also can check the video for Ubuntu / Linux](https://youtu.be/FSXtgdUzV_8)

Answer (score 0):

You can check logs file on writable/logs find error information,
If your logs information like :

```
CRITICAL - 2020-04-19 17:44:55 --> Invalid file: template/header.php
#0 F:\xampp\htdocs\ppdb\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\View\View.php(224): CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException::forInvalidFile('template/header...')
```

And go fix your error, in my case i am wrong typed name on controller file

Answer (score 0):

env file is coming with env without . than you just need to rename it with .env and change your production environment to development.

Answer (score 0):

> **CodeIgniter Error:  Whoops! We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later...**

When we installing CodeIgniter, that we are getting this message.

**Step-1:**

By Default, CodeIgniter app is running in "production" environment. we have to change it to development environment.

```
In Root folder change: env to .env
```

Search in .env file and Change `# CI_ENVIRONMENT = production` to `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development`

(please check # is removed)

Now Error will be visible in the browser.

**Step-2:**

Now, Error may show like these..

> **CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException:**
> **The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded: intl.**

```
Open [xampp]
Click on [Apache Config]
Open File: /php/php.ini
```

Now, Search for `;extension=intl` and remove the `;`

```
extension=intl
```

Save the `php.ini` file and restart Apache(server).